# Django annotated queryset vs model properties

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have model with custom manager (replaced from properties) that annotate queryset by pseudo fields (adds some annotation inside `get_queryset`). And its cool because I have one database query per list and so on.
But in some cases this is a problem. For example I want to get `my_annotated_field` inside signal function or with Django Rest Framework on save ViewSet (where we didn't get object via my manager). Model class doesn't have those fields. 
Is there way to solve this problem without extra query like `obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=obj.id)`?

Comment: Also with use_for_related_fields I get ProgrammingError: subquery has too many columns.